# Checking the platform support for pub dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any script or filter for checking platform support for pub dependencies? I am using http package for calling apis and want to ensure whether it has support for web?

Comment: try https://pub.green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you go on pub.dev you have labels to indicate which platforms the package supports. For example the package http you mentionned is written in pure Dart and supports every platforms (including web) you can check this on its pub page like this:

[image]

And if you are searching a package on pub.dev, by applying the filter `Flutter` you can then filter by platform supported:

[image]