# pub.dev API to get platform support and license information of packages

Tags: dart-pub, flutter-pub

The goal is to get this platform support info and the license information of a specific package via API:
[image: Information visible on the pub.dev/packages/ website, i'd like to retrieve via API]

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66730593/checking-the-platform-support-for-pub-dependencies), I'd like to retrieve the platform support of my used packages in my flutter or dart projects **BUT via API**.

Any help is highly appreciated.

I've checked the [API documentation](https://pub.dev/help/api) but did not find any related information. I'm hesitating to parse the website, as I believe there must be a different way to do this.

I've also checked the [api client](https://pub.dev/packages/pub_api_client) without any luck regarding platforms nor license information